# Empty XML node causes Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, null, decimal

How do I simply insert `NULL` if the node is empty or absent?

```sql
CREATE TABLE myxml (
    "hours" DECIMAL(11,2)
);

DECLARE @xml XML =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Employee>
        <NUMHOURS>0.5</NUMHOURS>
    </Employee>
    <Employee/>
    <Employee>
        <NUMHOURS>5</NUMHOURS>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <NUMHOURS/>
    </Employee>
</Data>';

INSERT INTO myxml ("hours")
SELECT 
    t.c.value('NUMHOURS[1]','DECIMAL(11,2)' )
FROM @xml.nodes('/Data/Employee') t(c)
```

The empty node `<NUMHOURS/>` causes:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I have tried:

```sql
NULLIF(t.c.value('NUMHOURS[1]','DECIMAL(11,2)' ),'')
```

but that seems to get processed after the fact resulting in the same error.

Comment: An empty node is not considered null by SQL Server, it is considered as an empty [b]string[/b]. In contrast the absence of a node is considered null. In your case you should use `CAST(NULLIF(t.c.value('NUMHOURS[1]','varchar(13)'), '') AS DECIMAL(11,2))`. You could change `varchar(13)` to something larger to accomodate for invalid values (that do not fit `decimal(11,2)`)

Comment: or you can try `SELECT  t.c.value('(./text())[1]','DECIMAL(11,2)') FROM    @xml.nodes('/Data/Employee/NUMHOURS') t (c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide a default value for invalid numbers:

```
select  case
            when ISNUMERIC(t.c.value('NUMHOURS[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')) <> 1 then NULL
            else t.c.value('NUMHOURS[1]', 'decimal(11,2)')
        end
    from @xml.nodes('/Data/Employee') t(c)
```

Comment: The question was how to insert `NULL` so I edited your answer to match. Thanks!

Comment: The question was how to insert NULL for empty or absent nodes, not for invalid values. IMHO invalid values should fail, or even better the xml should be validated against a DTD or XSD before being handed to SQL Server.

Comment: I like this straight approach, +1 from my side. You might be interested in another solution, where the cast is done internally. I find this very helpful while dealing with XML in a typesafe way...

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better approach: (should be at least faster with many rows...):

```
SELECT t.c.value('let $x:=NUMHOURS[1] return $x cast as xs:decimal?','decimal(11,2)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Data/Employee') t(c);
```

The `cast as xs:decimal?` will cast the value to decimal if possible, or return null. Thus the final `'decimal(11,2)'` has no type conversion issue any more...